# parsing JSON data to render high chart graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts

This is my Sample Json, I am trying to display this data as a high charts graph,

My plan is to choose battery Average on Y-axis and on x-axis os-version.

So I can compare each model with all os-versions.

For example, As shown in the image

values as battery average
city names will be as Os-version,
each projected bar in the graph is same model but with diffrent OS version.

I could not figure it out how to parse Json data to display as it in the graph

[image]

```
[
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5X",
      "osversion": "7.0",
      "batteryavg": "100",
      "sampleyqty": "42"
   },
   {
      "model": "LG-H961S",
      "osversion": "6.0",
      "batteryavg": "98",
      "sampleyqty": "73"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5X",
      "osversion": "5.1.0",
      "batteryavg": "50",
      "sampleyqty": "53"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6P",
      "osversion": "6.2.0",
      "batteryavg": "100",
      "sampleyqty": "55"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5",
      "osversion": "6.0",
      "batteryavg": "20",
      "sampleyqty": "9"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 4",
      "osversion": "5.1",
      "batteryavg": "98",
      "sampleyqty": "4"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6P",
      "osversion": "7.1.1",
      "batteryavg": "12",
      "sampleyqty": "22"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6P",
      "osversion": "7.1.1",
      "batteryavg": "46",
      "sampleyqty": "64"
   },
   {
      "model": "F5121",
      "osversion": "6.0.1",
      "batteryavg": "94",
      "sampleyqty": "15"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5",
      "osversion": "5.1",
      "batteryavg": "34",
      "sampleyqty": "55"
   },
   {
      "model": "SM-A500F",
      "osversion": "5.0.2",
      "batteryavg": "44",
      "sampleyqty": "33"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5",
      "osversion": "5.1",
      "batteryavg": "74",
      "sampleyqty": "81"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 4",
      "osversion": "5.1",
      "batteryavg": "75",
      "sampleyqty": "62"
   },
   {
      "model": "REDMI NOTE 3",
      "osversion": "5.0.2",
      "batteryavg": "13",
      "sampleyqty": "12"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5",
      "osversion": "5.1",
      "batteryavg": "87",
      "sampleyqty": "72"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5X",
      "osversion": "7.0",
      "batteryavg": "52",
      "sampleyqty": "21"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6P",
      "osversion": "7.1.1",
      "batteryavg": "85",
      "sampleyqty": "34"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6P",
      "osversion": "7.1.1",
      "batteryavg": "56",
      "sampleyqty": "51"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6P",
      "osversion": "7.1.1",
      "batteryavg": "56",
      "sampleyqty": "11"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6P",
      "osversion": "7.1.1",
      "batteryavg": "86",
      "sampleyqty": "22"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6",
      "osversion": "7.0",
      "batteryavg": "88",
      "sampleyqty": "11"
   },
   {
      "model": "SAMSUNG GALAXY S6",
      "osversion": "5.0",
      "batteryavg": "23",
      "sampleyqty": "84"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6P",
      "osversion": "7.1.1",
      "batteryavg": "87",
      "sampleyqty": "12"
   },
   {
      "model": "SAMSUNG GALAXY S6",
      "osversion": "5.0",
      "batteryavg": "65",
      "sampleyqty": "42"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 4",
      "osversion": "5.1",
      "batteryavg": "56",
      "sampleyqty": "32"
   },
   {
      "model": "LG-H961S",
      "osversion": "6.0",
      "batteryavg": "64",
      "sampleyqty": "54"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6P",
      "osversion": "6.0",
      "batteryavg": "53",
      "sampleyqty": "17"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5X",
      "osversion": "7.0",
      "batteryavg": "75",
      "sampleyqty": "32"
   },
   {
      "model": "F5321",
      "osversion": "6.0.1",
      "batteryavg": "64",
      "sampleyqty": "52"
   },
   {
      "model": "F5321",
      "osversion": "6.0.1",
      "batteryavg": "64",
      "sampleyqty": "22"
   },
   {
      "model": "ALE-L21",
      "osversion": "5.0.1",
      "batteryavg": "76",
      "sampleyqty": "52"
   },
   {
      "model": "HUAWEI MT7-TL10",
      "osversion": "6.0",
      "batteryavg": "53",
      "sampleyqty": "4"
   },
   {
      "model": "F5321",
      "osversion": "6.0.1",
      "batteryavg": "43",
      "sampleyqty": "51"
   },
   {
      "model": "HUAWEI MT7-TL10",
      "osversion": "6.0",
      "batteryavg": "22",
      "sampleyqty": "20"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5X",
      "osversion": "7.0",
      "batteryavg": "32",
      "sampleyqty": "31"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6P",
      "osversion": "6.0",
      "batteryavg": "74",
      "sampleyqty": "13"
   },
   {
      "model": "F5321",
      "osversion": "6.0.1",
      "batteryavg": "86",
      "sampleyqty": "52"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 5",
      "osversion": "6.0",
      "batteryavg": "54",
      "sampleyqty": "22"
   },
   {
      "model": "NEXUS 6P",
      "osversion": "6.0",
      "batteryavg": "77",
      "sampleyqty": "32"
   },
   {
      "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5X",
      "osversion": "7.0",
      "batteryavg": "99",
      "sampleyqty": "12"
   }
]
```

I am expecting userSeriesData data as

```
[{
    "data": [
        ["GOOGLE NEXUS 5X", 100],
        ["NEXUS 6P", 77],
        ["HUAWEI MT7-TL10", 53],
        ["LG-H961S", 64],
        ["GOOGLE NEXUS 5", 20],
        ....,
        ....,
        so on

    ],
    "osversion": "6.0"
},{
    "data": [
        ["GOOGLE NEXUS 5X", 50],
        ["GOOGLE NEXUS4", 98],
        ["GOOGLE NEXUS 5", 34],
        ....,
        ....,
        so on

    ],
    "osversion": "5.1.0"
}]
```

This is how i started:

```
const userSeriesData = userData.reduce((topAccum, parent, index) => {
    if (parent && Object.keys(parent).length > 0) {
        const childReduce = Object.keys(parent).reduce((childAccum, child, i) => {
            childAccum.osversion = parent['osversion']
            childAccum.data.push(parent['modelcode'], parent['sampleqty'])
            return childAccum
        }, {
            osversion: '',
            data: []
        })
        topAccum.series.push(childReduce)
    }
    return topAccum;
}, {
    series: []
})
```

JFYI: Sample JSON is dummy data, but it will look more or less same, with random OS versions, model number, battery average values

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete solution using part of your data:

```
const json = [{
  "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5X",
  "osversion": "7.0",
  "batteryavg": "100",
  "sampleyqty": "42"
}, {
  "model": "LG-H961S",
  "osversion": "6.0",
  "batteryavg": "98",
  "sampleyqty": "73"
}, {
  "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5X",
  "osversion": "5.1.0",
  "batteryavg": "50",
  "sampleyqty": "53"
}, {
  "model": "NEXUS 6P",
  "osversion": "6.2.0",
  "batteryavg": "100",
  "sampleyqty": "55"
}, {
  "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5",
  "osversion": "6.0",
  "batteryavg": "20",
  "sampleyqty": "9"
}, {
  "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 4",
  "osversion": "5.1",
  "batteryavg": "98",
  "sampleyqty": "4"
}, {
  "model": "NEXUS 6P",
  "osversion": "7.1.1",
  "batteryavg": "12",
  "sampleyqty": "22"
}, {
  "model": "NEXUS 6P",
  "osversion": "7.1.1",
  "batteryavg": "46",
  "sampleyqty": "64"
}, {
  "model": "F5121",
  "osversion": "6.0.1",
  "batteryavg": "94",
  "sampleyqty": "15"
}, {
  "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5",
  "osversion": "5.1",
  "batteryavg": "34",
  "sampleyqty": "55"
}, {
  "model": "SM-A500F",
  "osversion": "5.0.2",
  "batteryavg": "44",
  "sampleyqty": "33"
}, {
  "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5",
  "osversion": "5.1",
  "batteryavg": "74",
  "sampleyqty": "81"
}, {
  "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 4",
  "osversion": "5.1",
  "batteryavg": "75",
  "sampleyqty": "62"
}, {
  "model": "REDMI NOTE 3",
  "osversion": "5.0.2",
  "batteryavg": "13",
  "sampleyqty": "12"
}, {
  "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5",
  "osversion": "5.1",
  "batteryavg": "87",
  "sampleyqty": "72"
}, {
  "model": "GOOGLE NEXUS 5X",
  "osversion": "7.0",
  "batteryavg": "52",
  "sampleyqty": "21"
}]

// Create categories object in order to remove duplicates
const cats = {}
json.forEach((o) => cats[o.model] = 1)
const categories = Object.keys(cats)

// Parse your data
let series = json.reduce((acc, o) => {
    // Check if array already defined
    if (acc[o.osversion] && acc[o.osversion].data) {
      // Push to array new values
      acc[o.osversion].data.push({x: categories.indexOf(o.model), y: Number(o.batteryavg)})
    } else {
      // Create new array with first value
      acc[o.osversion] = { data: [{x: categories.indexOf(o.model), y: Number(o.batteryavg)}] }
    }
    return acc
  }, {})

// Convert object to array
series = Object.keys(series).map((key) => {
series[key].name = key
  return series[key]
})

series = series.map(serie => {
serie.data.sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x)
  return serie
})
console.log(series, categories)

// Chart options
const options = {
xAxis: { categories: categories },
chart: { type: 'column' },
  series: series
}

// Create chart
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options)
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/t698oqmm/

Example output:
[image]

Comment: Hej Thanks for your Help. One problem though, In series Data array, first two elements in each array were not correctly formatted, any specific reason  ?

Comment: oops, Now i realised, this is solutions seems to be wrong. only first Model shows correct display, 2nd group contains mix of diffrent Models. and also 3rd group

my wish was to seperate each model into a group with diffrent osverison column bars

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "Relatorios/getJobsPie",
                data:  { "startDate" : datastart, "endDate": dataend , "cliente" : $("#cliente").val() , 'statusjob':$("#status").val()  , 'search' :$("#search").val()},
                success: function($response) {
                        response = $.parseJSON(reponse);
                        var objects =[];
                        $.each(response, function(k, v) {
                            var date = new Date(v.data_conclusao);
                            objects.push([date.getMonth(), v.qnt.toNum()]);
                        }); 

                        var datos = [{
                            name: 'Name',
                            data: objects      
                        }];     

                        $('.piechart').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                marginTop: 80,          
                                type: 'column',
                                spacingLeft: -15
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            },      
                            series: datos
                        })                          

                }
            });
```